# Iphone Screen recording

Tags: ios, objective-c, video-capture, screen-recording

in my application I am recording device screen. while recording on some portion of my device screen, camera is opened. while I am playing the recording the part on which camera was opened is appearing as black. How can I solve this problem so that the camera part is also added in the recording.

Comment: You are just to recored your screen. use this http://www.tekrevue.com/tip/record-iphone-screen-quicktime/. it is working for camera too.

Comment: @Shoaib: Sorry to say but there is nothing about the screen recording with camera opned.

Comment: This seems like a super user Q but I have same issue so +1

Comment: iOS 11 will finally allow screen recording.

Answer (score 0):

Use the inbuilt OSX QuickTime and plug in your iPhone/iPad/iPod to record directly from your device.

Answer (score 0):

I have written a script that you can run to record your iphone screen.

Select your iPhone or iPad manually from the list of devices in QuickTime Player and run the script you’ll see your device’s screen replicated in the QuickTime window and gets recored.

**Create a shell script and the following:**

```
osascript <<EOD
tell application "QuickTime Player"
    activate
    start (new movie recording)
    delay 5
    tell application "System Events"
          key down {command}
          keystroke "w"
          key up {command}
          key down {command}
          keystroke "s"
          key up {command}
    end  tell
end tell
EOD
```